# VBA code for finding a partial string match

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to use this code but modified so that it finds any cells that contain the words Abuse Neglect (like a partial match) - and then subsequently deletes the row.  Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub TakeOutAllOtherCourses()
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "D").Value) = "Abuse Neglect" Then
'Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents ' USE THIS TO CLEAR CONTENTS BUT NOT DELETE ROW
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: There are definitely examples of how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208261/partial-cellor-string-match-in-excel-macro/ - among others.

Comment: Do you mean to match "Abuse" *or* "Neglect", or match "Abuse Neglect"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial cell(or string) match in excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208261/partial-cellor-string-match-in-excel-macro)

Answer (score 2):

Try Instr

```
Sub TakeOutAllOtherCourses()
last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For i = last To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Cells(i, "D").Value, "Abuse Neglect") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Check how `Like` operator works in this [link (Like Operator - Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator)

Code:

```
Sub TakeOutAllOtherCourses()
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "D").Value) Like "Abuse Neglect*" Then
'Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.ClearContents ' USE THIS TO CLEAR CONTENTS BUT NOT DELETE ROW
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's perfect!! Exactly what I was looking for - I just didn't know how to add in the "like"  You're awesome!

Comment: @Andrew Upvote or accept the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of future readers. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

Should your column D have no blanks, here’s a possibile (but untested) way with neither AutoFilter nor loops:

```
Sub TakeOutAllOtherCourses()
    With Range("D1", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        .Replace What:="Abuse Neglect*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```